# Why can’t I enable Sign in with Apple for my App ID in the Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles menu?

Tags: apple-sign-in

When I register an App ID in the *Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles* menu and choose explicit bundle id I can't find Sign in with Apple in the *Capabilities* tab, however Apple's developer documentation states that you can enable Sign in with Apple for your App ID in the *Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles* menu. Does anyone know what's going on?

[image: Screenshots1]

[image: Screenshots2]

[image: Screenshots3]

[image: Screenshots4]